# Ansible copy module. "Source not found"

Tags: ansible

I want to copy files from my ansible controller to a remote machine. When i run the playbook with -vvv i get the error "Source /path/to/file/file.txt not found". I have become: yes in my playbook as well as for this specific task. I also tried using the become_user: root but that did not work. The directory I am trying to access is owned by nagios so I also tried become_user: nagios but I got the same error. The permissions on the directory are "drwx------" but since I am using become: yes this shouldn't be an issue right? Here's a part of my playbook:

```
- name: Send file to client
  become: true
  become_user: root
  src: /path/to/file.txt
  dest: /remote/path/
  owner: nagios
  group: nagios
  mode: '0644'
  remote_src: yes
```

Answer (score 5):

If you *"want to copy files from ansible controller"* disable *remote_src*. This is the default hence you can delete this attribute as well.

```yaml
 remote_src: false
```

---

Notes

- `become: yes` and `become_user: root` has no effect at the originating/master machine. This escalates privilege at the remote host.
- The user who is running *ansible-playbook* at the master machine must be able to access the file.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. So i removed remote_src, become and become_user from this task. Thanks for clarifying what each of these modules actually do , it clarified things for me. After I removed these modules from my task and ran my playbook it failed at the same time but gave the error "Could not find or access /path/to/file.txt' on the Ansible contorller. If you are using a module and expect the file to to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option'.  Just to add I have become: yes added to the top of my playbook so this should give me the necessary privileges.